# ReferenceError: primordials is not defined - gulp 4.0.2 and node.js 16.14.0

Tags: node.js, gulp

Please note, I'm very noob to this sort of thing and apologies if this has been resolved elsewhere (I've looked but haven't found a solution to my specific issue regarding this error) but I have node.js installed v16.14.0 and I've installed gulp CLI version 2.3.0, Local version 4.0.2 and I receive the following error when I run gulp:

```html
C:\userscript-master>gulp
[09:31:42] Using gulpfile C:\userscript-master\gulpfile.js
[09:31:42] Starting 'default'...
[09:31:42] Starting 'build-dev'...
[09:31:42] Starting 'build-zendesk'...
[09:31:42] Starting 'build-uiv'...
[09:31:42] Finished 'build-zendesk' after 134 ms
[09:31:42] Finished 'build-uiv' after 169 ms
[09:31:42] Starting 'build-dev-main'...
[09:31:43] Finished 'build-dev-main' after 719 ms
[09:31:43] Starting 'lint-dev-changed'...
[09:31:45] Finished 'lint-dev-changed' after 2.79 s
[09:31:45] Finished 'build-dev' after 3.68 s
[09:31:45] Starting 'watch'...
[09:31:46] 'watch' errored after 528 ms
[09:31:46] ReferenceError: primordials is not defined
    at fs.js:47:5
    at req_ (C:\userscript-master\node_modules\natives\index.js:143:24)
    at Object.req [as require] (C:\userscript-master\node_modules\natives\index.js:55:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\userscript-master\node_modules\vinyl-file\node_modules\graceful-fs\fs.js:1:37)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
[09:31:46] 'default' errored after 4.21 s
```

I've no idea what's wrong nor where it is going wrong and I would very much appreciate any insight to resolve this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?  Are you trying to use a Zendesk Node.js client library?  Could you provide links or documentation to the code you are trying to run?

Comment: I'm trying to have gulp watch for changes to the userscript I'm editing in Visual Studio Code for ZenDesk. What happens is I run gulp before I edit the userscript in Visual Studio Code via CMD run as Admin (path directory is correct) and I end up with the error I posted in my question above. I've no idea why this happens nor what is going wrong. Thanks.